# How to hide radio pins from v-radio in vuetify 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

is anyone know how to hide/make the entire radio button pins gone in vuetify v-radio?

my radio button before and after:

[first radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QvBM.png)

[image: my second radio button]

i already search some post and some of them recommended about using `true-icon=""` and `false-icon=""` but the radio button pins is just invisible but it still there and eat the space like in my second image. i also already try to add `.v-input--selection-controls__input { display: none !important; }` in style but i think the new vuetify 3 have a new way to overwrite but i still haven't find how to do it.
is there any other way to make the radio pins gone entirely so the space is left only for the label?

Comment: then i do after i install it? doesnt icon-font only for setting the icon? what i need is to hide the button pin completely so its not taking space

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```css
.v-selection-control__wrapper {
  display: none !important
}
```

Comment: i already try that but sadly it still doesnt work